# Django: How to migrate from ManyToMany to ForeignKey?

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models, database-migration, django-migrations

I'm building a REST API and server using Django and Django Rest Framework. We are using a postgres database.

I need to simplify a badly designed relation. We have a model (`House`) that has a `ManyToMany` relationship to another (`City`). In reality it would be enough when this is a `ForeignKey` relationship.

I googled and couldn't find any blog posts or docs how to properly migrate in this direction. I could only find the other way (FK to M2M).

I'm 98% sure that all the data on the server will be consistent with a FK relationship (meaning I'm pretty sure all houses only have one city). We need to change the relationship for several reasons and aren't able to keep the M2M.

I'm afraid to just change the model and running `makemigrations` and `migrate`. I was wondering, how do you properly migrate from M2M to FK? Are there any caveats I have to take into account? How can I deal with data if surprisingly there are houses with multiple city's? The data set is still quite small (less than 10k entries) if that matters.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**EDIT** First create a DB backup

First create a new temporary FK relationship

```
_city = models.ForeignKey(...)
```

and make a migration

```
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
```

You then need to create a [new *data* migration](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/migrations/#data-migrations) in the relevant app by creating an empty migration file:

```
python manage.py makemigrations --empty myhouseapp
```

and in that file manually assign the new relationship from the M2M to the FK. It will look something like:

```
from django.db import migrations


def save_city_fk(apps, schema):
    City = apps.get_model('myapp', 'City')
    House = apps.get_model('myapp', 'House')
    for house in House.objects.all():
        house._city = house.cities.all().first()  # Or whatever criterea you want
        house.save()


def save_city_m2m(apps, schema):
    # This should do the reverse
    City = apps.get_model('myapp', 'City')
    House = apps.get_model('myapp', 'House')
    for house in House.objects.all():
        if house._city:
            house.cities.add(house._city)


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.RunPython(save_city_fk, save_city_m2m)
    ]
```

Remove the M2M field, and create another migration.

```
python manage.py makemigrations
```

Rename the FK from `_city` to `city` and create a final migration

```
python manage.py makemigrations
```

Then migrate:

```
python manage.py migrate
```

Comment: Wow, thanks, this sounds perfect. I will try it out now!

Comment: No problem, just be careful with these sort of migrations. It's easy to get in a mess.

Comment: Just dont forget that if new houses keep getting added after running the data migration you also need to migrate them, therefore it might sense that you eg. add the populating of the new foreignkey field also to the `save()` method of new instances...

Comment: I'm done now and I will accept your answer. However I will add an answer describing in detail what I did  Thank you very much! 

Comment: Thank you for the great answer. Btw just change
python manage.py makemigration --empty myhouseapp
to
python manage.py makemigrations --empty myhouseapp
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Based on [Timmy's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/396300/timmy-omahony) [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54704869/django-how-to-migrate-from-manytomany-to-foreignkey/54704989#54704989) here is what I did:

1. I added a field like this `city = models.ForeignKey(City, related_name='has_houses', blank=True, null=True)` to avoid the `related_name` for reverse relations and to have the FK blank. Then I ran `makemigrations` and `migrate`.
2. Next, I ran `python manage.py makemigrations --empty houses` because my app is named `houses`.
3. I added the code for the migration (see below). Then I ran `migrate`.
4. I deleted the M2M field and the `related_name`, `null` and `blank` constraints and ran `makemigrations` and `migrate` one last time.

Code for the migration:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# Generated by Django 1.11.15 on 2019-02-15 09:09
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.db import migrations


def save_city_fk(apps, schema):
    City = apps.get_model('cities', 'City')
    House = apps.get_model('houses', 'House')
    for house in House.objects.all():
        house.city = house.cities.all().first()
        house.save()


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('houses', '0003_auto_20190215_0949'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.RunPython(save_city_fk),
    ]
```

Comment: One thing to watch out with this is that if you run your migrations in reverse you'll lose your data. Notice how @Timmy had two functions for migrations; one for the forward migration and one for the reverse migration. This way if you unapply the migration (i.e. you migrate to an earlier state) the data will be restored as it originally was.

Comment: @LomaxOnTheRun Even with the reverse function, data loss may happen anyway since he's picking the ```first()``` object?

Answer (score 1):

First obviously you need to make sure (by making the appropriate query) that you really only have one city per house. If there are houses which have more than one city, you need to resolve the conflict by deleting cities from the relationship, splitting houses etc.

After that, you can do it in steps:

- create a new FK in `House`, migrate and populate it with the one city id from the old m2m relationship
- rename the m2m field, migrate, then give the new FK the name of the old m2m field if desired and migrate again
- check if your queries work and adapt them as necessary
- when satisfied that everything works, delete the old m2m field – only after migrating this step will you lose the ability to roll back the db

Answer (score 0):

for M2M relation it is better to build a new MOdel to represent the relation. following is the example of an`employee having multiple designation and designation obtained by multiple employees

```
class Designation(models.Model):
    desig_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=60, unique=True)
    job_discription = models.CharField(max_length=2000)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

class Employee(AbstractUser):
    middle_name = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True,  null=True)
    basic_salary = models.FloatField(default=1)
    designation = models.ManyToManyField(Designation, default=None, blank=True,
                                     through='EmployeeDesignation')
    certification = models.ManyToManyField(Certification, default=None, null=True, blank=True,
                                        through='EmployeeCertification')
    emp_img = models.FileField(default=None,upload_to='employees')
    leaves_allowed = models.IntegerField(default=25)
    leave_balance = models.IntegerField(default=25)
    leave_count = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    objects = EmployeeManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.first_name+' '+self.last_name

class EmployeeDesignation(models.Model):
    desig = models.ForeignKey(Designation, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    emp = models.ForeignKey(Employee, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = (('emp', 'desig'),)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have seen that the answers are saying that you have to create multiple migration files to do it but this is not great practice and after some time you may squash your migrations together.
Just create an empty migration or create an automatic migration by using:

```bash
python manage.py makemigrations
```

and provide a default value for the existing instances.

After that, you can change the file and modify the changes and apply the data migration without losing any data.
Create the functions and run them after adding the new fields and after that, you can delete them and rename the new field properly.

```py
migrations.AddField(...),

migrations.RunPython(save_city_fk),

migrations.RemoveField(...),

migrations.AlterField(...),
```

The order ***is*** important.